# Solve a third order ODE, no boundary values

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have:
\begin{align}
y &= it^{\frac{1}{3}}\sin(i\omega x)\\
v(y) &= ut^{\frac{-1}{3}}\\
u &= vt^{\frac{1}{3}}
\end{align}

I determine $u_x, u_t,$ and $u_{xxx}$ in terms of $\frac{dv}{dy}$ and substitute it in
\begin{equation}
u_t - uu_x - u_{xxx} = 0
\end{equation}

The desired outcome is to have an ODE where I can now define $v$ and so define $u$.

This is what I have:

\begin{align}
u_x &= -\omega t^{\frac{2}{3}}\cos(i \omega x)v_y\\
u_t &= \frac{1}{3}t^{-\frac{2}{3}}(yv_y + v)\\
u_{xxx} &= -\omega^3t^{\frac{2}{3}}\cos(i \omega x) [ \cos^2(i\omega x)v_{yyy} + 2it^{\frac{1}{3}}\sin(i \omega x)v_{yy} + v_y]
\end{align}

So when I make the substitution I have:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{3}t^{-\frac{2}{3}}(yv_y + v) + \omega t \cos(i \omega x)vv_y + \omega^3t^{\frac{2}{3}}\cos(i \omega x) [ \cos^2(i\omega x)v_{yyy} + 2it^{\frac{1}{3}}\sin(i \omega x)v_{yy} + v_y]=0
\end{equation}

Though I have transitioned from a PDE to an ODE, I don't see how to go about solving this.

Comment: Maybe try calculating $v_y$ and $v_{yy}$ ?

Comment: those are not known.  $v=h(y)$ and $y$ are differential invariants.